Указание часового пояса для запроса
Есть ли возможность указать часовой пояс для одного select ?  Чтобы не повлиять на всю сессию. Или только отдельное соединение для этого запроса создавать? (MySQL)

Ничто не мешает в соединении изменить пояс, выполнить запрос, затем восстановить пояс. А вот одним запросом это не получится сделать.

что за запрос то?
